# use of ObjectInputValidation in java

Tags: java, serialization

I have a question regarding `ObjectInputValidation` interface in java. This interface is used to validate graph after deserialization. My question is if one can validate the object in `readObject` method, then why should we use `ObjectInputValidation`?

Answer (score 1):

Serialization can save object graphs and with ObjectInputValidation you can check the state of the entire graph, which is done when all the graph is restored.